# MySQL upgrade 5.7 to 8.0 with Keyring encrytption failed to complete upgrade

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, percona-server

I ran the mysql community installer on Red Hat 7.9 over a 5.7.36 installation.

First, I ran xtrabackup for all dbs
Then I stopped mysqld
Then I ran yum install
Everything ended ok
I got the below error on the error log when trying to start mysqld back.

```
[System] [MY-013381] [Server] Server upgrade from '50700' to '80032' started.
[ERROR] [MY-013178] [Server] Execution of server-side SQL statement 'ALTER TABLE mysql.plugin TABLESPACE = mysql; ' failed with error code = 3825, error message = 'Request to create 'encrypted' table while using an 'unencrypted' tablespace.'.
[ERROR] [MY-013380] [Server] Failed to upgrade server.
[ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

My databases are encrypted using keyring.

The my.cnf config file:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]

early-plugin-load=keyring_file.so

sql_mode=""

bind-address = 0.0.0.0
datadir = /var/lib/mysql

innodb_file_per_table = ON
key_buffer_size = 16M
log-error = /var/log/mysqld.log
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
max_binlog_size = 1000M
max_connections = 150
port = 3306
skip-external-locking
socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
tmpdir = /tmp
user = mysql

#server-id = 11211
#log-bin = mysql-bin

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2560M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M

innodb_redo_log_capacity=2GB

[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
host = localhost
```

Reviewed permissions over both /var/lib/mysql dir and files and also over /var/lib/mysql-keyring/keyring file.

Comment: I've given up on MySQL 8.0. The only way to upgrade is basically to dump all data and import to a freshly installed instance. In-place upgrade is broken in multiple ways.

Comment: Bill, I figured out what the issue was and posted it in an answer below. Everything else worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SOLVED]

The problem happened when the mysql_upgrade step failed to decrypt mysql.plugin table, so to avoid this I just rolled back to 5.7, decrypted all MySQL db tables and ran the upgrade again.

```
alter table engine_cost ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table gtid_executed ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table help_category ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table help_keyword ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table help_relation ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table help_topic ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table innodb_index_stats ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table innodb_table_stats ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table plugin ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table server_cost ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table servers ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table slave_master_info ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table slave_relay_log_info ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table slave_worker_info ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table time_zone ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table time_zone_leap_second ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table time_zone_name ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table time_zone_transition ENCRYPTION='N';
alter table time_zone_transition_type ENCRYPTION='N';
```

It worked fine.